# Styling depending on screen orientation in Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, styling, adaptive-design

I am styling on phone and tablet but how can I add the option also for orientation? this is all for portrait but how can I add option for horizontal orientation?

```
 <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="DocType">
                        <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <OnIdiom Phone="50" Tablet="80" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                 <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#F4F5F7"/>
             </Style>
```

Comment: Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=windows.

Comment: What Microsoft suggests is you override the `OnSizeAllocated` method in your page and set your `StackLayout`'s orientation accordingly. Sadly, there's no way to style for the orientation the same way it can be done with `OnIdiom` or `OnPlatform`. At least no way that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [OrientationStateTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.orientationstatetrigger?view=xamarin-forms) with [VisualStateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager) here is an example:

```
<Grid>
     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup>
               <VisualState
                    x:Name="Landscape">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                         <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Landscape" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                         <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
               </VisualState>
               <VisualState
                    x:Name="Portrait">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                         <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Portrait" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                         <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
           </VisualStateGroup>
      </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups> 
</Grid>
```

[Source](https://javiersuarezruiz.wordpress.com/2020/02/19/xamarin-forms-statetriggers/)

**EDIT**

#### `VisualStateManager` inside a style, combined with `OnIdiom`

```
<Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="DocType">
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom Phone="50" Tablet="80" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup>
               <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                         <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Landscape" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <OnIdiom Phone="Blue" Tablet="Green" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
               </VisualState>
               
               <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                         <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Portrait" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <OnIdiom Phone="Yellow" Tablet="Purple" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
           </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

in this example:

| Mode | Tablet | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Landscape** | Green | Blue |
| **Portrait** | Purple | Yellow |

Comment: I used the style example with an implicit style impacting 4 elements on the screen. Only the last f the four elements was affected by the style change. How can I get an implicit style controlled by visual state manager orientation?

Comment: Worth mentioning that you need to add this to the native project:

Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("StateTriggers_Experimental");