# Xamarin VisualState.StateTriggers not found in type VisualState

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, triggers

I'm trying to use an `OrientationStateTrigger` in `Xamarin`, so I can style elements based on the device's orientation.

I have copied an example from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100176/896631)

And this is my Xaml:

```
<ContentView.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="grid_master">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualState
                    x:Name="Landscape">
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Landscape" />
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState
                    x:Name="Portrait">
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Portrait" />
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Only the compiler doesn't recognise the VisualState.StateTriggers line and when hovering over it, the tooltip says

> 'The attachable property 'StateTriggers' was not found in type
> 'VisualState'.'

I am using XamarinForms version `3.1.0.697729` so it should be available in this version, right?

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here? Thanks

Comment: `Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.697729` is a little bit old, the newest one is `Xamarin.Forms.5.0.0.2578`. I've tested on the `Xamarin.Forms.5.0.0.2578` and the background can change as expected when switching from `Landscape` to `Portrait`.You may upgrade it to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the `Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.697729` is a little bit outdated, the newest one is `Xamarin.Forms.5.0.0.2578`.

I've tested the sample code below on the `Xamarin.Forms.5.0.0.2578` and the **background** can change as expected when switching the orientation from `Landscape` to `Portrait`. You may upgrade it to see if it works.

```
<!-- OrientationStateTrigger demo --> 
<Style x:Key="OrientationStateTriggerPageStyle"
               TargetType="ContentPage">
       <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Portrait" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                        Value="Blue" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Landscape" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                        Value="Red" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
         </Setter>
</Style>


<ContentPage
          -- omitted for brevity

             Style="{StaticResource OrientationStateTriggerPageStyle}">

    <Grid Margin="20">
        <Label Text="The page background color depends upon the device orientation."
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'm using this version due to limitations of the devices we're working with. But as far as I could tell, the StateTriggers were available since 3.0 so wondered if there was a way to get it working on my version?

Comment: @DevDave Thanks for the response. May I know the exact OS version of the device?

Comment: Android 7.1 Nougat

Comment: And also, please help provide the version of your Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio version is 15.9.49 (2017)

Comment: @DevDave I think it's related with the version of VS as when I'm hovering over it the VS can recognize it. The latest version of VS is  `17.5.4`.

Comment: OK thanks for your help, not sure I can change that either :)

Comment: No worries, I am glad to help you if you have any other questions.